# Can anyone explain me the DbContext.SubmitChanges() method while saving changes to database

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, console-application, linq-to-objects

**I am using Linq to Sql in my console application.**

I am into this scenario where I retrieve records from database and update each record and save by calling **DbContext.SubmitChanges()** `DbContext being my context object instance`

I see two scenarios.

- When I update 3 records (meaning 3 rows/objects out of which 2 rows belong to a table say 'A' and 1 row belongs to table say 'B') when I call the DbContext.SubmitChanges() at last ie: after updating all 3 records the SubmitChanges() method takes around 10 secs to exceute. **NOTE:**`just counted it roughly`
- When I update the same 3 records and call the DbContext.SubmitChanges() after every record update It executes in less than a second. So to say in detail I update 3 records and call SubmitChanges() 3 times ie: after every record update. The total execution time is less than a second.

Just wanted to know whats causing this execution delay??

Is it like if only one record is **updated** and **SubmitChanges() is** called, only this record gets updated. But when called after 3 records are updated the SubmitChanges() tries to update all the records in the collection?

Comment: You should monitor the database and see what statements are executed when it takes such a long time.

Comment: you mean I can see it by using SQL profiler or something?

Comment: In most scenario's I have used, the performance benefit is more in favour of the first scenario. But with the small mounts of updates still limited. You can see the SQL that is being executed with SQL profiler for sure. Perhaps locking or so. Provide the code if you want some more feedback